# Webpack "devtool eval" doesn't show correct files content in devtools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm having relatively simple webpack config file (below):

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/main.js",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
  devtool: "eval",
    module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      { 
        test   : /.js$/,
        loader : 'babel-loader' ,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I'm using `webpack-dev-server` to serve an app when in development with the following command `webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --port 9090 --content-base public/ --watch`.

I read that it's recommended using `eval` for source maps when in development, but it doesn't work for me. What I get in my devtools is as follows. It correctly shows files (`main.js` and `hello.js`) but it contains babel-transpiled content, not the original one. When I set it to `eval-source-map` it works fine.

What's wrong in my setup? Complete project for this question is available [here](https://github.com/mostr/webpack-devtool-eval-issue)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check official Webpack documentation for details of every Source Maps setting - http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool.

If you want original lines (not transpiled) use options listed in documentation table.

```
| Devtool                       | Quality                      |
| ----------------------------- | ---------------------------- |
| cheap-module-eval-source-map  | original source (lines only) |                  
| ----------------------------- | ---------------------------- |
| cheap-module-source-map       | original source (lines only) |                   
| ----------------------------- | ---------------------------- |
| eval-source-map               | original source              | 
| ----------------------------- | ---------------------------- |
| source-map                    | original source              |
```

Comment: Yup. Apparently I had hard time to grasp this table (quality column especially). Thanks for the hint.

Comment: An answer that consists only of a link is generally consider bad practice on SO. Please consider expanding on your answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: @Chris Added table with proper options